# The number of the subrings

Tags: abstract-algebra, ring-theory

There are only questions that finding the number of ideals in my book.

So I have a curious that how many each ring does have subrings.

How many number of the subring for given rings?

(Each of the below rings have an identity that $0=[0]_n $ for $mod n$ and unity $1=[1]_n $ for $mod n$

E.g. the ring $\mathbb Z_6 =\{0,1,2,3,4,5\}$ for $mod n$(unity is 1 and identity is 0)

1. $\mathbb Z_6$
2. $\mathbb Z_4$
3. $\mathbb Z_6  \times \mathbb Z_4$
4. $\mathbb Z_7$

P.s.) how many number of the subrings which is isomorphic with the ring $\mathbb Z_n$?

Comment: What's your definition for a ring? Is an identity required?

Comment: Yes. All of them have a identity. Let me edit my post.

Comment: So if you require every subring should contain an identity, then there are much fewer situations. Can you figure them out?

Comment: I just knew that $Z_n $'s all subrings are $<m> s.t.m|n$. But Can't  figure out the case $Z_6  \times Z_4$

Comment: What are their identities if you claim that every ring has an identity?

Comment: Please see my post. I edited. Sorry for confusing you.

Comment: @se-hyuckyang I believe Bach's point was that if $m\mid n$, $\langle m\rangle$ doesn't contain $1$ unless $m=1$. I believe that the subrings of $\Bbb{Z}_6\times \Bbb{Z}_4$ are the whole ring, and $(a,b)$ such that $a\equiv b\pmod{2}$.